# If $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$, show that $f(.)$ can only be a logarithmic function.

Tags: functional-equations

As the question states, show that the property exhibited can only be satisfied by a logarithmic function i.e no other family of functions can satisfy the above property.

Comment: What about the zero function?

Comment: @5xum, corrected thanks!

Comment: You can think of the zero function as $\log_\infty$. :P (Don't actually do this.)

Comment: See https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/the-functional-equation-fxy-fxfy/ . I think you must assume continuity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuity is necessary.

If $F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y)$, for all $x,y$ and $F$ discontinuous (such $F$ exist due to the Axiom of Choice, and in particular, the fact that $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ possesses a Hamel basis) and
$f(x)=F(\log x)$, then $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$, and $f$ is not logarithmic!

Answer (score 3):

With the assumption that $f$ is continuous, compute the partial derivatives; firstly wrt to $x$ then $y$
\begin{align}
yf'(xy) &=f'(x) \\
xf'(xy) &=f'(y) \\ 
\end{align}
Equating terms in $f(xy)$ we have
$$\frac{1}{y}f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}f'(y)$$
Or
$$xf'(x)=yf'(y)$$
Now, if you know anything about these equations you will notice something interesting about both sides of the equation above, allowing you to make the crucial step in obtaining a very simple ODE to solve; of which  the solution should be the one you are looking for.